# prove $\ T^* = T^{-1} \iff A^T = A^{-1} $

Tags: linear-algebra

$\ V = M_{n \times n }(\mathbb R) $ with inner product space $\ \langle A,B \rangle = tr(A^TB) $ let $\ T_A: V \rightarrow V  $ be the transformation $\ T_A(B) = AB $

Prove $\ T_A $ is unitary $\ (T^* = T^{-1})  ֿ\iff A $ is orthogonal ($\ A^T = A^{-1} $)

In the first direction I want to start with $\ A^T = A^{-1} $ and get to $\ T^* = T^{-1} $ so lets say I start with

$$\ \langle T_A(A^T), B \rangle \ = \ \langle A^T, T^*_A(B) \rangle \ = \ tr(A^T \cdot {\bar{A^T}}^T B) = tr(A^T \bar{A} B) = tr(A^{-1} AB) = tr(B)  $$

I'm not really sure what I'm doing here any if its the right direction how to proceed from here?

Comment: First, be consistent on using $T$ and $T_A$. Second, I guess  by "adjoint", you actually meant "self-adjoint", and that actually is defined as $T^* = T$ instead of "$T^* = T^{-1}$". Please edit your question carefully to avoid these confusing typos.

Comment: Also, use `\lange, \rangle` to typeset inner product symbols (instead of using "<, >" directly).

Comment: Sorry, the term I was actually referring to is unitary matrix. edited my question, hopefully it is written properly now.

Comment: If $V = M_{n \times n} (F)$ denotes the square matrix space equipped with the Frobenius inner product $\langle A, B \rangle = tr(B^{*} A),$ then do you want to show that $T_{A}^{*} = T_{A}^{-1}$ if and only if $A^{*} = A^{-1}?$ Also, if yes, then which direction do you find more difficult?

Comment: Yes! I'm not sure I understand why $\ \langle A, B \rangle = tr(B^*, A) $ I mean what is $\ B^* $ ? Is it just $\ T^*_A(B) $ ?

Comment: $B$ is a square matrix, so $B^{T}$ means transpose and $B^{*}$ means conjugate transpose. So transpose $B,$ then take the complex conjugate of every matrix element.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm still unsure why do I take the transpose and conjugate of $\ B$ since the inner space product is $\ T_A(B) = AB $ then $ T^*_A(B) = \bar{A^T} B $ or you just defined the outcome of that to be $\ B^* $ ?

Comment: Also I forgot to write the space if over $\ \mathbb R $ so I guess conjugate doesn't really matter

Comment: I wanted to use the adjoint as defined in Friedberg, Insel, and Spence in section 6.3 https://anujitspenjoymath.files.wordpress.com/2018/08/stephen_h-_friedberg_2c_arnold_j-_insel.pdf

Comment: @bm1125 If the space is over $\mathbb{R}$, I don't see the point to bring in conjugation into the play. The "unitary operator" could be replaced with "orthogonal operator", and $\bar{A}$ is simply $A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $V = M_{n \times n}(F)$ denote the square matrix space over $F,$ where $F$ is either $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}.$ Further, equip $V$ with the Frobenius inner product $\langle A, B \rangle = tr(B^{*}A),$ where $A, B \in V.$

Now, suppose that $A^{*} = A^{-1}.$ Then, for some $B, C \in V,$ we have
$$\langle B, C \rangle  = \langle IB, C \rangle = \langle A^{-1}AB, C \rangle = \langle A^{*}AB, C \rangle,$$
where $I$ denotes the identity matrix. Hence, the latter inner product is equivalent to
$$tr(C^{*}A^{*}AB) = tr((AC)^{*}AB) = \langle AB, AC \rangle.$$

Subsequently, we want to apply the definition of $T_{A}(B) = AB$ to obtain $$\langle AB, AC \rangle = \langle T_{A}(B), T_{A}(C) \rangle.$$
Then, the adjoint of $T_{A}$ satisfies
$$\langle T_{A}(B), T_{A}(C) \rangle = \langle (T_{A}^{*}T_{A})(B), C \rangle,$$
which implies $T_{A}^{*}T_{A}$ is the identity transformation. Thus, we can reach the desired conclusion...

The other direction is similar.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you help me understand though why does $\ \langle AB,AB \rangle $ implies $\ T^{-1} = T^* $ ?

Comment: Since $V$ is finite-dimensional, the adjoint is the unique linear operator that satisfies $\langle T_{A}(B), C \rangle= \langle B, T_{A}^{*}(C) \rangle,$ where $B, C \in V.$ From here, one can use the inner product properties to show that $\langle T_{A}^{*}(B), C\rangle = \langle B, T_{A}(C) \rangle,$ which is what I applied to obtain $\langle T_{A}(B), T_{A}(B) \rangle = \langle T_{A}^{*}(T_{A}(B)), B \rangle.$

Comment: Then, I used associativity to group  $T_{A}^{*}T_{A}$ into a product. Now, we have $(T_{A}^{*}T_{A})(B) = B,$ since we have a chain of equalities and it follows from inner product properties. Hence, the product must be the identity transformation, so the the adjoint is the inverse of $T_{A}.$

Comment: For the other direction, start with $\langle B, B \rangle = \langle I(B), B \rangle,$ where $I$ denotes the identity transformation. Then, substitute $I = T_{A}^{-1} T_{A},$ which is equivalent to $T_{A}^{*} T_{A}$ under the assumption that $T_{A}^{*} = T_{A}^{-1}.$

Comment: $\langle B,B \rangle = \langle (T^*_A T_A)(B),B \rangle$ does not necessarily imply that $(T^*_A T_A)(B) = B$. However, your answer is easily rectified by replacing $\langle B,B \rangle$ with $\langle B,C \rangle$ for another $C \in V$.

Comment: @MatthewBuck I have amended to your solution, but what is a counter example to the previous solution?

Comment: @sunspots Consider $v = (1,0) \in \mathbb{R}^2$. Anti-clockwise rotation by $\pi/4$ radians and scaling by $\sqrt{2}$ is a linear transformation, say $A$. Then $\langle Av,v \rangle = 1 = \langle v,v \rangle$, where $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ is the standard Euclidean product. But certainly $Av \ne v$.

Comment: Got it, thanks for the example.